# Making TCHAR* compatible with char*

Tags: c++, type-conversion

So a quick question how do I make TCHAR* (or wchar_t as its a macro) work with char*?

I am using the unicode character set.

The code that is the problem is:

```
 TCHAR* D3DDevTypeToString(D3DDEVTYPE devType) {
   switch (devType) {
      case D3DDEVTYPE_HAL:    
      return TEXT("D3DDEVTYPE_HAL");
      case D3DDEVTYPE_SW:     
      return TEXT("D3DDEVTYPE_SW");
      case D3DDEVTYPE_REF:    
      return TEXT("D3DDEVTYPE_REF");
      default:                
      return TEXT("Unknown devType");
      }
   }
```

The obvious solution is to change TCHAR* to char* but I would like to keep it as TCHAR* if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve here? Return a narrow char?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And yes I am using the unicode character set.

Then you cannot make TCHAR compatible with char. Because if you're using UCS, then TCHAR is wchar_t. The type `char` is not related in any way to `wchar_t`. You could do some work to convert the string (using e.g. `WideCharToMultiByte`), but then you'd lose Unicode support.

Comment: Using WideCharToMultiByte doesn't necessarily mean losing unicode support. WideCharToMultiByte can transform your UTF-16 wchar_t string into a UTF-8 char string.

Comment: @Jon: But as UTF-8, you have to treat the data as UTF-8. Don't write one of those programs which assumes that if you assume everything is UTF-8, you never have to worry about encodings ever again.

Comment: Certainly. I didn't mean to imply that conversion to a UTF-8 char* would solve all the problems. It's usually easier to simply deal with UTF-16 on windows.

Comment: @Jon: The reason I say that is that people often see "UTF-8 as a solution to all problems" -- UTF-8 is a transformation format, not a solution. That might not be what you meant, but "UTF-8 means you can still use the standard stuff in `<string.h>`" is completely incorrect information I see trumpeted in several places (Unix land in particular). If you define it as UTF-8 that's fine, but code has to be written to deal with that; it's not free. I'd suggest using a `typedef` to mark the method as returning something like `utf8Byte` instead of `char` to make more obvious that that is the intent.

Answer (score 2):

`TCHAR` could be `wchar_t` or `char`, depeding upon whether the macro `UNICODE` is defined or not.

- If the macro `UNICODE` is defined, then `TCHAR` means `wchar_t`. In this case, you cannot use `TCHAR` in place of, or with, `char`. It's dangerous!
- If it's not defined, then `TCHAR` means `char`. In this case, you can use `TCHAR` in place of, or with, `char`. After all, they're same now.

Answer (score 0):

Write a converter from UTF-16 to UTF-8 (or use the win32 API function if that's what it does).  Make it generic so it can work on char*, wchar_t*, std::string, and std::wstring.  Write a templated function string_cast and let the second parameter be figured out by the compiler.  Override string_cast for the different combinations you will be using.  Convert between TCHAR* to std::string with string_cast and then it doesn't matter how TCHAR is defined (assuming you overrode for both char and wchar_t.